# Present ViewController by Clicking CollectionViewCell inside TableView(with several sections)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a music app recently, and I'd like to know how to pass data from CollectionView to TableView which has several sections. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqaNr.jpg) is the home page of my project, and what I want to do is when user tap the image, it will precent another ViewController with the information about the picture. I already know how to present a ViewController by clicking CollectionViewCell inside TableView by delegate, but only if there's only one section.

The thing is that I have 5 sections in this page, and I also have 5 different models for encoding the JSON from API. So how I show the pictures is to send the image urls(from 5 models) to TableViewCell in each section like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: HomeTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? HomeTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.delegate = self

        switch homeSections[indexPath.section] {
        case .newReleases:
            if let newReleases = self.newReleases?.albums.items.map({$0.images[0].url}) {
            cell.getPictures = newReleases
            }
            return cell
        
        case .followSingers:
            if let currentlyFollowing = self.currentlyFollowing?.artists.items.map({$0.images[0].url}) {
                cell.getPictures = currentlyFollowing
                cell.isCircle = true
            }
            return cell
            
        case .catrgories:
            if let categories = self.musicCategory?.playlists.items.map({$0.images[0].url}) {
            cell.getPictures = categories
            }
            return cell
            
        case .artists:
            if let playlist = self.relatedArtists?.artists.map({$0.images[0].url}){
                cell.getPictures = playlist
            }
            return cell
            
        case .recentlyPlayed:
            if let recentlyPlayed = self.recentlyPlayed?.items?.map({$0.track.album.images[0].url}) {
                cell.getPictures = recentlyPlayed
            }
            return cell
        }
        
    }
```

However, when I want to pass the information which the user tap, there's nothing I can pass but indexPath. I've tried to declare the 5 different model types in TableViewCell, but I still don't know which section did the user tap. Does anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

Update:

To make the question more clearly, please refer to the information below.

In this page, I have a TableView and embed a CollectionView in the TableViewCell, and there's only one ImageView in the CollectionViewCell.

The "New Releases", "Currently Following" and "Categories" are the header of TableView. The "New Releases" is the first section, and the "Currently Following" is the second section, and so on.

Here is how I set cellForItem in CollectionView Delegate. It basically converts String to URL, and display the picture on the screen.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HomeCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? HomeCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
    
    guard let url = URL(string: getPictures[indexPath.row]) else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
        cell.myImageView.getImages(url: url)
    if isCircle == true {
        cell.myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.myImageView.frame.width/2
    }
    return cell
}
```

When the user taps the image, it will only trigger the didSelectItemAt in CollectionView. And I can only pass indexPath.row so far.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    delegate?.sendIndexPath(index: indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: First, well asked question. But I'm not sure why you cannot use `indexPath.section`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but which `indexPath.section` do you mean? TableView or CollectionView?

Comment: Now it's my turn to backtrack on my compliment. Can you describe more clearly the *actual* hierarchy involved here? Basically, you posted code for a UITableView delegate, and I'm not catching how a UICollectionView fits in properly. Also, maybe give some "debug values"? (I'm not trying to be vague or dense - but for instance, the female in red in the "Currently Following"... should I assume that's section 2 in the table and... what in the UICollectionView? Or am I being **way** off on everything?

Comment: One last question for clarification, since you posted code for UITableView only. Let's say a user taps on that female in red - what delegate method(s) get triggered? if more than one, in what order/ And what are the values in the indexPath(s)?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I should make it more clearly. I've updated the information in the article, thanks for your reminder!